# JDBC throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jdbc

I am not sure why this error is occuring as the column has data's in it and I am able to execute this statement using Toad

```
  try
    {
      System.out.println("Executing SQL");
      String r = "select ID from PA_STR_RTL";
      System.out.println("Starting Executing SQL");
      st = con.createStatement();

      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(r);

      while(rs.next())
        {
             int r1 = rs.getInt("ID");
             System.out.println(r1);
         }
     }
  catch(SQLException e)
      {

       e.printStackTrace();

      }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the null pointer?  This will tell you if it is the connection (my guess) or something else.  Which will allow you to get a more useful answer.

Comment: This is the stracktrace Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ksk.Ksupdate.connect(Ksupdate.java:141)
 at ksk.Ksupdate.actionPerformed(Ksupdate.java:95)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed

Comment: There's no stacktrace posted here.  Try editing your post to add it rather than leaving it as a comment.

Comment: I pressed enter too soon

Comment: There's no way for us to know which line of your code is line 141 in the class.  Can you share that info?

Comment: 141: st = con.createStatement();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, the connection is null.  This means that the problem isn't in any of the code you posted.  It is before that when you get the connection.

Typically this means you have a try/catch around creating the connection and are ignoring the error.  The most common errors are not having the database driver jar in your classpath (class not found) or not having a valid connection string.

Comment: the connection seems to be fine as it went past this code. THe system.out.println is printed so the connection happened           try
   {
          DriverManager.getConnection(cn, a,  a1);
          System.out.println("Entered DB");
   }
   catch(SQLException e){
          cantconnect();
   }

Comment: I just checked and the jar file has been added to Eclipse and also have a try catch to find out if there is no driver present and the catch isn't executed as it found the driver and went to the next step

Comment: Thanks. There was a problem in creating the connection and now it got resolved